# Count array elements of all collection properties

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have the following collections:

collection A

```json
{
    "comments" : [{"text" : "z"}, {"text" : "b"}]
}
```

collection B

```json
{
    "comments" : [{"text" : "a"}]
}
```

Each collection has a property `comments` with an array of comments.

How can I get the total number of comments in my collections?

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $unwind: "$comments" },
    { $group: {
           _id: "$_id", 
           sum: { $sum: 1 } 
       }
    } 
]);
```